# Compile Sass in PhpStorm

Tags: css, ruby, sass, phpstorm

I need help. I installed ruby and Sass. After install I added watcher to scss file in PhpStorm. I wrote some code and PhpStorm auto compile it into css file. Everything worked perfect, but after I change scss file, PhpStorm wrote error message

```
cmd.exe /D /C C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update style.scss:style.css
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: CP852 and UTF-8
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and scss file has not been compiled.

If I remove watcher from PhpStorm and add new the same, again first compile works perfect, but the other do not work.

Do someone know, why compile does not work?

Comment: Show screenshot of that File Watcher settings. I do not understand why do you use `cmd.exe /D/ C` there -- you do not need it. Have a look at how it should look (adjust paths/params to your needs): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20703621/783119

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/k9oumxoc7/

Comment: Thnx. It looks OK for me. Based on a message I may only say that for some reason there is a incompatibility between encodings -- compiler expectesUTF-8 but CP852 was given/detected -- not sure what that means and why it happened. I may only suggest checking internet and other answers here for `incompatible character encodings: CP852 and UTF-8` -- this has to be related to the default encoding in your system.

Comment: For me is interesting that first compile work well, but the other don't work. Find issue I have tried, but I didn't find anything what I would use.

Comment: Really do not know -- for me it's more of a Ruby issue. In any case: feel free to submit an issue to JB's support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732228/sass-filewatcher-for-webstorm). Try using `node-sass-cli`.

Comment: PhpStorms has its own instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/compiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html